# PHP - Google Speech API: Class 'Google\Cloud\Speech\SpeechClient' not found

Tags: php, composer-php, google-cloud-platform

I was hoping someone could help me figure out how to get google's speech to text api running.

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/speech/api

The specific code I'm trying to run is: src/functions/transcribe_sync.php

with a line added at the end to call the function:

```
transcribe_sync("mono.flac", 'en-US');
```

It can't locate a dependency. I've been playing around with composer but haven't been able to figure it out.

Heres the error:

```
php transcribe_sync.php
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Google\Cloud\Speech\SpeechClient' not found in /home/bhaag/Documents/php-docs-samples-master/speech/api/src/functions/transcribe_sync.php:45
Stack trace:
#0 /home/bhaag/Documents/php-docs-samples-master/speech/api/src/functions/transcribe_sync.php(55): Google\Cloud\Samples\Speech\transcribe_sync('mono.flac', 'en-US')
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/bhaag/Documents/php-docs-samples-master/speech/api/src/functions/transcribe_sync.php on line 45
```

Heres my composer.json file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "google/cloud-speech": "^0.2",
        "google/cloud-storage": "^1.0",
        "google/gax": "^0.8.1",
        "google/proto-client-php": "^0.10.0",
        "symfony/console": "^3.0",
        "php-ffmpeg/php-ffmpeg": "^0.9.3"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Google\\Cloud\\Samples\\Speech\\": "src/"
        },
        "files": [
            "src/functions/streaming_recognize.php",
            "src/functions/transcribe_async.php",
            "src/functions/transcribe_async_gcs.php",
            "src/functions/transcribe_sync.php",
            "src/functions/transcribe_sync_gcs.php"
        ]
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~4"
    }
}
```

I've been able to get the full speech sample running so I know I have all the credentials set up correctly but it seemed really cryptic to work with  the full sample (speech.php in the main directory).

Am I going about this the wrong way? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The samples are constructed in such a way as to be run via the `speech.php` file in the root.  To run `transcribe_sync.php` directly, you'll need to include the composer autoloader:

```
require_once "/path/to/vendor/autoload.php";
```

Replace the `/path/to` with the path to where your composer dependencies are installed.

Alternatively, (I recommend this option), to run without any changes to the sample code, run this at the command line:

```
php speech.php transcribe mono.flac
```

Comment: oh thanks! That did solve the dependency issue but it still gives me an error: 
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'namespace' (T_NAMESPACE) in /home/bhaag/Documents/php-docs-samples-master/speech/api/transcribe_sync.php on line 28

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I added "require_once "/path/to/vendor/autoload.php"" as the first line after <?php, was that right?

Comment: Be sure to add a semicolon at the end of that line. I've updated my answer to show that.

Comment: Woah. I can't believe I missed a semi-colon. Not used to php's errors yet. Thanks for pointing it out and thanks for solving my problem