# LARAVEL: main(): Failed opening required 'vendor\autoload.php'

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, autoload

I followed [this documentation](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-php/blob/master/AUTHENTICATION.md) and I keep getting that `main(): Failed opening required 'vendor\autoload.php'` error and I ran `composer install` but still get the same error. I'm using Laravel and I'm calling this from a Controller..

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Google\Cloud\Speech\SpeechClient;
use Google\Cloud\Speech\StorageClient;
use App\Model\FilesModel;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class FilesController extends Controller
{

    private $project_id;
    private $speech;
    private $options;
    private $storage;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $storage = new StorageClient([
            'keyFile' => json_decode(file_get_contents(public_path() . '/key.json'), true)
        ]);
    ....
```

How do I bypass this issue?

Comment: have you updated your composer using `composer update` command?

Comment: Yes I did, and I also ran `composer dump-autoload` which was also suggested in one of the questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41209349/requirevendor-autoload-php-failed-to-open-stream but still same issue.

Comment: no need to write this line `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` in laravel, because autoload file automatically loaded as a part of bootstraping

Comment: I would get this error: `"Class 'Google\Cloud\Speech\StorageClient' not found"`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44287349/php-google-speech-api-class-google-cloud-speech-speechclient-not-found

Comment: where you kept your Google Library folder? inside public?

Comment: Inside the vendor directory

Comment: place it inside public, because i don't think you added it via composer, you directly download and paste it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

first of all no need to do that! because it's included in all pages...
if you insist doing this I think the problem is the address of autoload file which have to be:

```
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Comment: Cool, this solved my problem other than the fact that instead of using `use Google\Cloud\Storage\StorageClient;`, I also had a typo problem.

Answer (score 0):

I solved deleting the "require '../vendor/autoload.php';" sentence from Controller and works in bouth environments (local and server). I am working with an Openpay integration.

That was hard for me, because i was trying to solve editing the routes or updating composer and stuff like that.